# Possible to open a SSH tunnel using Java?

Tags: java, ssh

I want to open up a SSH tunnel in a Java program, so that the rest of the system will also have access to the connection (e.g. if I forward a port for a database to the localhost I should be able to open the database in another program)... In other words what I need to do it to create a Java wrapper for something like the unix command ssh. However I need the program to be cross platform, so if possible I would like to use a library from Java.

Is this possible (I have been looking at different libraries, but have not been able to create the tunnel so the rest of the system can use it yet)

Comment: @Bobby sometimes using such a solution is good.

Comment: @Bobby SSH tunnels are the swiss army knife of heavily firewalled environments. As long as everything is meant to be temporary they are a lot easier to use than setting up full blown VPNs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library definitely makes this easy and supports port forwarding:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect(timeout);
session.setPortForwardingL(listenPort, destHost, destPort);
```

Comment: Notes:it is only port forwarding,but not a dynamic sock forwarding which plink-D did.otherwise,you will get I/O exception:(java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Reply from SOCKS server has bad version.

Answer (score 5):

I had a success with article from beanizer based on Jcraft's Jsch. Here are more details: http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Articles/Java-ssh-tunneling-with-jsch.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) ?

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Ganymede SSH-2 for exactly this purpose with great success, worked first time actually, much to my surprise.